# Is it possible to debug No unique bean of type is defined found 0

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I am having some trouble with NoSuchBeanDefinitionException...

Here is my class :

```
package fr.aaaa;
@Component
public class Computation {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Computation.class);

    public Computation() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:applicationContext.xml");
        Computation computer = context.getBean(Computation.class);
    }
}
```

my applicationContext.xml file was located in `src/main/resources/com/acc/resources/`.
I copied it in `src/main/resources/` and no more exception were raised.

How can I change the classpath in order for Spring to find the xml file in `src/main/resources/com/acc/resources/` ?

Comment: `classpath:com/acc/resources/applicationContext.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the path:

```
... ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:com/acc/resources/applicationContext.xml");
```